# Repeat Column titles in SSRS . How to achieve it

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, reporting, ssrs-2012

I have 2 Data sets. The Dataset 1 is to be used for Report ColumnNames whereas Dataset 2 is used for it's value.

[Dataset 1 and Dataset2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsgRg.jpg)

[Now my Final Report Should look like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLxR1.jpg)

Please guide me on how i can proceed. I am new to this SSRS Reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there I'll try to walk you through the steps:

What you need to do is first get your data sets into a workable format. I've done that by using a `CROSS JOIN` between Dataset1 and Dataset2:

[image]

Then I used the report wizard to create the report:
[image]

Step 1 select the datasource:

[image]

Step 2 Select the report type (here I've selected a Tabular report)

[image]

Step 3 design the report table:

[image]

Step 4 Choose the layout for the table (I've chosen stepped):

[image]

click finish and you will now be taken to the design window for the report.

[image]

Step 5 Alter the report design:

1. Cut and paste the columns [ID],[Name],[Desc], and [Amt] to get the following result:

[image]

2. Now you remove the unwanted columns :

[image]

3. Now you can remove unwanted rows:

[image]

please note that a pop up will appear on the rows within the groupings with the following messgae:

[image]

choose delete rows and associated groups.

4. You can now add a row outside of the group to clearly show separate groups:

[image]

And here is the report:

[image]

Comment: kamran, i don't see a grouping of ID anywhere. How are you able to get the report?? I am not able to get it. I am getting just column header and details. The headers are not repeated at all for every id.

Also any approach without cross join??

Comment: @Novice_Techie the grouping is done at Step 3 where we group in the following order: ID, NAME, DESC, AMT. As for the cross join the data set required is a Cartesian product of table_A and table_B so the easiest way to achive this was via a cross join. How large will your two tables be?

Comment: Kamran, i got it. Thanks!! I am able to get it.